# If $t_nx_n\to y$ and $A\subseteq [0, \infty)$ is syndetic, is there $r_n\to\infty$ that $r_n\in A$ and $r_nx_n\to y$?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, topological-groups

For $A, B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$, we denote
$$A+B= \{a+b: a\in A, b\in B\},$$ and
$$A^{-1} +B= \{t: \text{ there is } a\in A \text{ such that } a+t\in B\}.$$

A subset $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$  is called syndetic, if there is a compact set $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\mathbb{R}^+= K^{-1}+B$

A subset $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$  is called  $g$-  syndetic, if there is a compact set $K$ of $\mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\mathbb{R}^+= K+B$

One can check that every non-empty subset $B\subseteq \mathbb{R}^+$ with $0\in B$  is syndetic if and only it is $g$-syndetic.

Assume  $\mathcal{T}=\{T(t)\}_{t\geq 0}$ is $C_0$-semigroup of bounded operators on Banach space $X$.

There exist a strictly increasing sequence
$\{t_n\}\subseteq [0, \infty)$ with $t_n\to \infty$ and a sequence
$\{x_n\}$ in $X$  such that $\lim_{n\to \infty}T(t_n)x_n=y$.

Assume that  $A\subseteq [0, \infty)$ is syndetic. Is there a sequence $\{r_n\}\subseteq A$ with $r_n\to \infty$ and $\lim_{n\to \infty}T(r_n)x_n= \lim_{n\to \infty}T(t_n)x_n=y$?